# On validating email address in mysql on stored procedure

Tags: mysql, validation, email, stored-procedures

I have a problem with not getting through the valid email address in mysql stored procedure here's what suppose to happen:

```
DELIMITER go
Create procedure AddMessages(
  Out MessageID tinyint(11),
 IN iFirstName varchar(30),
 IN iLastName varchar(30),
 IN iTextBox varchar(400),
 IN iEmailAddress varchar(30))
BEGIN
/*declaring local variable*/

  If(iFirstName='') then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name';
  Elseif(iLastName='') then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the Last Name';
   Elseif(iTextBox='') then
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the Message Box';
  Elseif(iEmailAddress='') then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
/*   Checking if email address is not valid*/
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the Email Address';
  Elseif(iEmailaddress!='^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*\\.[a‌​-zA-Z]{2,4}$') then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please enter the correct email address'
;
Else
/* insert the messages*/
    insert into Messages(  
    FirstName,
     LastName,
      Messagetextbox,
     EmailAddress 
     )
    Values
    (
    iFirstName,
     iLastName ,
     iTextBox ,
     iEmailAddress
    );
    set MessageID = last_insert_id();  
     end if;
    End
```

When I tested it by using

```
 set @new_id = null;
call AddMessages(@new_id,'Jamie','Jones','Hello','Jones3sdfsdf@gmail.com');
select @new_id;
```

The result I got was that I kept getting the message saying Please
enter the correct email address and I already tested out without using
`@` and it works but for some reason validate email suppose to pass not
displaying the same message.

Comment: You can't use `!=` to do a regular expression match. Use `IF iEmailaddress NOT RLIKE '...'`

Comment: `=` and `!=` do exact string matching, not regular expression.

Comment: Come on, please, **please** allow for more than thirty characters for an email address. You're going to see a lot of people bump up against that limit because of how `david.jones@corporationlatetotheparty.com` is not an unusual address. Use `VARCHAR(255)` for any generic text field unless you have a very compelling reason to alter the default.

Comment: This regular expression also rejects a lot of actual, legitimate addresses. I strongly recommend you abandon all hope of verifying addresses using anything other than a simple test: A) Does it contain an `@` character. B) Can you deliver email to it? If so, it's a valid email address. `b@co` is technically a valid address, and with number of [gTLDs growing almost daily](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) it's impossible to predict what is or isn't a valid domain. `.weatherchannel` is a valid domain extension. We're well beyond `.com` and `.us`.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
Elseif (iEmailaddress NOT RLIKE '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*\\.[a‌​-zA-Z]{2,4}$') then
```

`RLIKE` is the operator for matching a regular expression. `=` and `!=` match the string exactly.

Comment: Technically correct, but wow, is that regular expression from the question ever *bad*.

Comment: @tadman I didn't even bother to examine the regexp, I felt it was good enough to help him with the SQL syntax.